# Unix C code cp in system()

Tags: system, cp

I have a C code..
i which I have following code for UNIX:

```
l_iRet = system( "/bin/cp -p g_acOutputLogName g_acOutPutFilePath");
```

when I am running the binary generated..I am getting the following error:

```
cp: cannot access g_acOutputLogName
```

Can any one help me out?

Comment: The error message is easy to understand.  Maybe you need to specify the full path name of the `g_acOutputLogName` file, or run your program from the correct directory.

Comment: why are you calling system command? you could use a c library for copying files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `g_acOutputLogName` and `g_acOutPutFilePath` are `char[]` (or `char*`) variables in your program, rather than the actual paths involved.

You need to use the values stored therein, rather than the variable names, for example:

```
char command[512];    
snprintf( command, sizeof command, "/bin/cp -p %s %s", 
          g_acOutputLogName, g_acOutPutFilePath );
l_iRet = system( command );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..
It was really helpful..
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You should generally prefer the exec family of functions over the system function. The system function passes the command to the shell which means that you need to worry about command injection and accidental parameter expansion. The way to call a subprocess using exec is as follows:

```
pid_t child;
child = fork();
if (child == -1) {
  perror("Could not fork");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else if (child == 0) {
  execlp("/bin/cp", g_acOutputLogName, g_acOutPutFilePath, NULL);
  perror("Could not exec");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
  int childstatus;
  if (waitpid(child, &childstatus, 0) == -1) {
    perror("Wait failed");
  }
  if (!(WIFEXITED(childstatus) && WEXITSTATUS(childstatus) == EXIT_SUCCESS)) {
    printf("Copy failed\n");
  } 
}
```